# Parsing a (complicated) URL

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, parser

This is a tricky one that requires a level of Excel function mastery I don't currently have. I have been studying Excel's site for way too long and I'm still not progressing.

I am trying to take a complicated URL like:

> http://dp18776.live.domiain.net/active/MO_Mi_WFM

and parse it so that I get this:

> live.domain.net

The closest I have gotten is with this:

> http://dp18776.live.domiain.net

My logic:

```
=LEFT(A17, SEARCH(".net",A17)+3)
```

The reason I can't stop there is because the local part can be variable across the thousands of records, whereas only the domain is (e.g. live.domain.net) constant.

I also know I need to use the MID function, I was testing what I could get away with on more basic functions, but the bigger wrench in the works is that I need to be able to key off ".net" to retrieve the domain, so I need to set the starting point in MID() as ".net" - len(domain)

Would anyone be able to help me complete this formula?

Comment: Is there always a subnet? Does it always have numbers? Is it always the same length?

Comment: Yes, there is always a subnet, either delimited by 2x '.'s or or 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everybody here seems to focus on the `.com` or `.net`, but domains don't always end with `.com` or `.net`... however, they always end before the **`/`**.

So first find where the host name begins:

```
=FIND("://", A1) + LEN("://")
=FIND("://", A1) + 3
```

Then find the first slash afterwards – that's where the host name *ends*:

```
=FIND("/", A1, FIND("://", A1) + 3)
```

Or, just in case there's no path at all:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("/", A1, FIND("://", A1) + 3), LEN(A1) + 1)
```

And extract everything in between:

```
=MID(A1;FIND("://";A1)+3;IFERROR(FIND("/";A1;FIND("://";A1)+3);LEN(A1)+1)-(FIND("://";A1)+3))

A1: https://www.example.com/foo/bar
A2: =FIND("://";A1)+3
A3: =IFERROR(FIND("/";A1;A2);LEN(A1)+1)
A4: =MID(A1;A2;A3-A2)
```

If you want to throw away the leftmost domain component, you can use `FIND(".",A1)`:

```
=MID(A1;FIND(".";A1)+1;IFERROR(FIND("/";A1;FIND(".";A1)+1);LEN(A1)+1)-(FIND(".";A1)+1))

A1: https://www.example.com/foo/bar
A2: =FIND(".";A1)+1
A3: =IFERROR(FIND("/";A1;A2);LEN(A1)+1)
A4: =MID(A1;A2;A3-A2)
```

For Salesforce, with no error checks:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("://",A1)+3,FIND("/",A1,FIND("://",A1)+3)-(FIND("://",A1)+3))

=MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,FIND("/",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-(FIND(".",A1)+1))
```

---

Note: This *still* has a few assumptions – e.g. it won't work right if the URLs have a `username@domain` or `username:password@domain`. The `FIND(".")` version also assumes there are at least two domain components and won't work right with `https://example/foo` – it needs some extra IFERROR() checks for that.

Comment: This is the best answer. Good job, grawity. This is what I came here to add, but you already nailed it.

Comment: Ditto what @picobit said, this is impressive, thank you!! Only nuance I have now: when trying to import into Salesforce as a formula field, Salesforce does not have an equivalent to IFERROR functions, so I need to re-write for that. 
Any tips on how best to tackle?

Comment: If you're certain that all URLs will have a path (at least an empty path, i.e. `http://foo/` and not `http://foo`) then you can omit IFERROR() entirely. Otherwise, find out how Salesforce reports errors from FIND() or SEARCH()...

Comment: @grawity from what I have seen, the fields will have always have some kind of http://foo.domain.com/string/moreStrings/yetAnotherString/, so I am not super worried. 
I am getting hung up on how to de-Nest the IFERROR statement: It looks like IFERROR(FIND("/",A34,FIND(".",A34)+1),LEN(A34)+1) is the chunk, but there is a minus operator succeeding the statement: -(FIND(".";A1)+1))

Comment: @grawity in other words, is the '-(FIND(".";A1)+1))' string part of that IFERROR function?

Comment: @GPP: No, of course it isn't. It's a regular minus sign. (See edit)

Comment: @grawity sure, but what is that statement being subtracted from?

Comment: @GPP: From the return value of IFERROR(...).

Comment: Thanks Grawity! I marked yours as the answer to the question, but there's an additional challenge: Some of the urls have numbers appended like this:
http://13723.live.streamingurl.com:80/VBNCASA_SC, which means the string comes out like this:
live.streamingurl.com:80
Any suggestions on how to fix? I can't use IFERROR, but another nested IF statement?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [regexp via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/1511077)

and get your hostname with something like that:

```
https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\/.*
```

group 1:

```
live.domain.net
```

Comment: Intriguing, thanks for jumping in! I am trying to stick with the lesser-powered 'LEFT' and 'MID' functions since I am ultimately aiming to turn this into a Salesforce formula field (I was directed here).
Is this a realistic expectation? (I am digging into the Regex links on that answer link btw)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the conditions are of your local part and where your hangups are, I'd search for the extension and then the first `.` as you don't have a `www.`. If you do - search for the second `.`. I'll provide the parts and then the actual formula.

Searching for whatever extension you need to find.

```
=IFERROR((SEARCH(".com",A1)),0)+IFERROR((SEARCH(".net",A1)),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH(".org",A1),0)
```

Searching for your first `.`

```
=SEARCH(".",A1)
```

Then combine them in `=MID()`

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(".",A1)+1,IFERROR((SEARCH(".com",A1)),0)+IFERROR((SEARCH(".net",A1)),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH(".org",A1),0)-SEARCH(".",A1)+3)
```

If there isn't always a local part, then it may get trickier. There are also some other ways to do it if your local string is always the same length or always has a specific string, or certain values, etc.

You can get rid of the `iferror` portions if you *always* know the extension, or you can add additional extensions.